# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin(x\pi n!)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, diophantine-approximation

Since [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419162/sequence-of-function-and-convergence-field) question is closed, I'm asking it myself.

> Let $M=\{x\in \mathbb R|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin(x\pi n!)\text{ converges}\}$
>
> Prove that there is no $a,b\in \mathbb R$ such that $(a,b)\subset M$ (ie $M$ has empty interior).

It has been proved that $e\in M$, and it's easy to prove that $\mathbb Q \subset M$ (essentially because if $n\in \mathbb N$, then $\sin(n\pi)=0$). I haven't managed to prove $M$ has empty interior. The idea would be to point out a dense subset of $M^c$.

Noting that $\sin(x\pi n!)\approx 0 \iff \exists k_n\in \mathbb Z, x\approx \frac{k_n}{n!}$, we're looking for $x$'s that are badly approximated by rationals. A result by Liouville states that if $x$ is an irrational algebraic number of degree $m$, there exists some $c_x$ such that for all $p,q\in \mathbb Z$, $\left|x-\frac pq \right|> \frac{c_x}{q^m}$.

In our case, if $x$ is an irrational algebraic number of degree $m$, then for each $n$ and any $p\in \mathbb Z$, $$\left|xn!\pi -p\pi \right|>\frac{c_x\pi}{(n!)^{m-1}}$$
Hence $|\sin(xn!\pi)|>\left|\sin\left(\frac{c_x\pi}{(n!)^{m-1}}\right) \right|$.

However, nothing may be derived from this lower bound (the RHS goes to $0$ too fast).

Comment: What are the downvote and the close vote for ?

Comment: this was asked before

Comment: Related: [$\sin(2\pi nx)$ does not converge for $x \in (0,1/2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24898/272831)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that any number $x$ between $[0, 1]$ can be written in the form

$$ x = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{k!}, \qquad a_k \in \{0, \cdots, k-1\}. $$

Mimicking [my previous computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419113/proving-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-sine-pi-n-converges/2419131#2419131), we have

$$ \sin(x\pi n!) = (-1)^{n a_{n-1} + a_n} \sin\left( \pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n+k}}{(n+1)\cdots(n+k)} \right). $$

Here an important observation is that

$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n+k}}{(n+1)\cdots(n+k)}
\leq \frac{a_{n+1}+1}{n+1}. \tag{*} $$

Now think of $a_k$ as function of $x$ (as in the usual $n$-ary expansion, ambiguity arises only when $x$ is rational, a Lebesgue-null set). Then each $a_k$ defines a random variable having uniform distribution over the set $\{0,\cdots,k-1\}$ and $\{a_k\}$ are mutually independent. Moreover,

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{a_k}{k} - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \frac{1}{4}\right) = \infty $$

as $k\to\infty$ and thus by the 2nd Borel-Cantelli theorem, $\frac{1}{4} < \frac{a_k}{k} < \frac{3}{4}$ holds for infinitely many $k$ for almost every $x$ in $[0, 1]$. This, together with $\text{(*)}$, shows that

$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} | \sin(x\pi n!) | \geq \sin(\pi/4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$

holds for almost every $x$ in $[0, 1]$. Since no $x \in M$ can satisfy this, it follows that $M$ is a Lebesgue-null set and its interior is empty.

Comment: Riemann wrote that the series converges at $x=\frac{e-\frac 1e}4$. What do you think about that ? [p.95 here](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMA_1873__5__79_1.pdf)

Comment: @GabrielRomon, I was a bit careless when writing my previous comment. Now I can assure that the sum does not converge. Indeed, with $$x=\frac{e-e^{-1}}{4}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!},\qquad a_n=\begin{cases}n/2,&\text{$n$ even}\\0,&\text{$n$ odd}\end{cases}$$the computation above tells that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sin((4k+r)!\pi x)=\begin{cases}1,&r\equiv1\pmod{4}\\-1,&r\equiv3\pmod{4}\\0,&r\equiv0,2\pmod{4}\end{cases}.$$This also matches numerical computation. But I suspect that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin(n!\pi x)$ converges in Cesaro sense.

Comment: right, Riemann definitely did a mistake !

Comment: I have a question, how to prove the expansion form of $x$ and (*)?

Answer (score 2):

A result of Kolmogorov states that if $n_k$ is a Hadamard lacunary sequence, i.e., $\frac{n_k}{n_{k-1}}>\rho$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and some $\rho>1$, then the trigonometric series
\begin{align}\sum_k a_k\cos(n_k x+\theta_k)\tag{1}\label{one}\end{align}
converges (diverges) almost everywhere iff $\sum_k a^2_k$ converges (diverges).

This can be seen in Zygmund, A., *Trigonometric Series Vol. 1*, 3rd edition, Cambridge University Press, pp. 202-204.

The convergence can also be seen in the sense of a Toeplitz summation but that is not too relevant for the purposes of this posting.

The series in the problem is of the form \eqref{one} with $a_k\equiv1$, $\theta_k\equiv\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $n_k=k!$. Then the series in the OP diverges almost surely, and so the set $M$ is of measure zero and has no interior.